# Add-ins with ribbon menus cannot open from the “More Add-ins” menu in the Outlook Web App

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-web-app

I work on an add-in for Microsoft Outlook, and we’ve noticed that in the Outlook Web App our Add-in cannot open at all when we attempt to open it from the “More Add-ins” button.  The menu that lists more add-ins will open, but then clicking our add-in closes the menu with nothing happening.

We used to have our Add-in’s ribbon menu open when it was clicked here.  We first encountered the broken behavior yesterday (7/28/22).

We’ve checked if this is happening to all Add-ins with a list of ribbon commands, and this seems to be the case for all Add-ins. To reproduce this error, we’ve implemented Microsoft’s example for Add-in commands (https://github.com/officedev/outlook-add-in-command-demo) by uploading to https://officeapp.s3.amazonaws.com/command-demo-manifest.xml and installing from URL.

Clicking the “Add-In Command” closes the menu, and nothing happens.

[image: More Addins Menu]

The expected behavior is a list of commands should show:

[image: Expected behavior]

Additional Note: The ribbon command menu correctly appears if the Add-in is pinned to the toolbar via Settings->Mail->Customize actions->Toolbar. This is how we were able to take a screenshot to demonstrate the expected behavior.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for reaching out. This is a known issue within the Outlook web client. We are working on a fix for this issue, but do not have a timeline to share at this moment.